# c3p0 CombopooledDataSource not committing SQL update

Tags: java, sql, c3p0

I am using a pooled datasource (msaccess database) to update local database (client side using h2 database) via an application i made. 
The problem i have is when submitting a request say "INSERT INTO USERS (NAME, CODE) VALUES (Me ,`hfd5255fd4`);" the app runs perfectly , nothing is reported in the error log BUT nothing has changed in the database either.
The code i am using is as follows

```
private static Connection getDatabase() throws Exception {


    cpds.setDriverClass("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    // loads the jdbc driver
    cpds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:ucanaccess://"
            + (new File("Ressources/filter.mdb").getAbsolutePath()));
    cpds.setUser("admin");
    cpds.setPassword("ibnsina");
    cpds.setAutoCommitOnClose(false);
 return cpds.getConnection(); //tried removing this , but no effect
}
----doing some other stuff---
private static updating() throws exception{
conn = getDatabase();

    File fileUpload = new File(logPath + "UploadLog.txt");
    BufferedReader readerUpload = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            fileUpload));
    String Uploadingline = "";
    StringBuffer secondaryline = new StringBuffer();
    if (readerUpload.ready()) {
        System.out.println("Uploadtxt ready");
        Statement stUpload = conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Stupload ready");
        while ((Uploadingline = readerUpload.readLine()) != null) {

            if (Uploadingline.endsWith(";")) {
                secondaryline.append(Uploadingline);
                /*stUpload.executeUpdate(secondaryline.toString()); tried this to execute each line separatly*/
                stUpload.addBatch(secondaryline.toString());
                System.out.println("Reading line :" + secondaryline);
                secondaryline.setLength(0);

            } else {
                secondaryline.append(Uploadingline);

            }

        }
        stUpload.executeBatch();
        stUpload.clearBatch();
        conn.commit(); //i even tried adding this to make it commit even tho autocommit is by default ON
        stUpload.close();}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not create a new `DataSource` for each connection, you need to create just one `DataSource` and use that to get `Connection`s. Remember to `close()` them as that will return the connection to the pool.

You should do something like:

```
// There should only ever be one of these.
private static final DataSource ds = makeDataSource();

private static DataSource makeDataSource() {
    ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    cpds.setDriverClass("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    // loads the jdbc driver
    cpds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:ucanaccess://"
            + (new File("Ressources/filter.mdb").getAbsolutePath()));
    cpds.setUser("admin");
    cpds.setPassword("ibnsina");
    cpds.setAutoCommitOnClose(false);
    return cpds;
}

private static Connection getConnection () {
    return ds.getConnection();
}

private static void releaseConnection (Connection conn) {
    conn.commit();
    conn.close();
}

private static void updating() {
    Connection conn = getConnection();
    try {
        //...
    } finally {
        releaseConnection(conn);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is much, much better than what the poster offers. A minor nitpick: the releaseConnection() method, which is called from finally, ought not include conn.commit(). That's important for two reasons: 1) if an Exception occurs in the body of the method you call updating(), work is likely only partially done, and you'll want to call rollback() [in a catch clause] rather than commit(); and 2) if an Exception occurs during conn.commit(), the call to conn.close() will be skipped, potentially preventing Connections from ever being returned to the pool.

Comment: If you want transactional behavior, call conn.setAutoCommit(false) at the top of the try block, do your work, and call conn.commit() at the bottom of the try block. put conn.rollback() in a catch clause and conn.close() in the finally.

Comment: After adding the `throws Exception` shouldn't the `return cpds` type be ComboPooledDatasource instead of Datasource ?? i am getting a compilation error there . @ Steve Waldman: conn.rollback() isn't required since it is a one way transaction, but if i wanted to include it later: if i call upon rollback() wouldn't it cancel all the changes made even those done before the stUpload.executebatch() is called?

Comment: @SteveWaldman - I agree - I posted it that way because OP's code was committing on close. Doing it this way is indeed a potential smell.

Comment: @RahmouneMedEl-habib - A `ComboPooledDatasource` implements the `javax.sql.DataSource` interface so treating it like one makes for tidier code. Your compilation error is unlikely to be caused by that. What error is it reporting?

Comment: @OldCurudmgeon :'Type mismatch: cannot convert from ComboPooledDataSource to DataSource` EDIT: The answer was in your response the Datasource i used was sun.jdbc.odbc.ee.DataSource ...Type mismatch is fixed now. However after testing the above code the application still doesn't commit the Update request

Comment: @RahmouneMedEl-habib - In that case you know now that it is not your use of the ComboPooledDatasource that is your issue. I would suggest you examine your queries.

Comment: Duely noted, i was thinking there should've been an error msg (in the logs ) if the queries were wrong, i'll check them anyway